# Expand range (low, high) to values with index

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

My data looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
    index = c(1, 2, 3),
    lo = c(1, 3, 6),
    hi = c(2, 5, 10)
)

#   index lo hi
# 1     1  1  2
# 2     2  3  5
# 3     3  6 10
```

I want to tidy the low - high range to expanded values:

```
df_new <- data.frame(
    index = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3),
    value = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
)

#    index value
# 1      1     1
# 2      1     2
# 3      2     3
# 4      2     4
# 5      2     5
# 6      3     6
# 7      3     7
# 8      3     8
# 9      3     9
# 10     3    10
```

Comment: Link? Couldn't find before posting @DirtySockSniffer

Comment: Haven't found one yet, but you could do something like `stack(with(df, setNames(Map(":", lo, hi), index)))` or `library(data.table); setDT(df)[, lo:hi, by = index]`

Comment: Or `library(dplyr); df %>% group_by(index) %>% do(data.frame(value = .$lo:.$hi))`.

Comment: Maybe `stack(lapply(split(df, df$index), function(x) x$lo:x$hi))`

Comment: Are you looking for a result specific to dplyr and/or tidyr?

Comment: @DirtySockSniffer I am. It follows that there should be an answer with `complete` or similar. I quite like @Axeman's comment. It's very elegant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two options with `dplyr` and `tidyr`, the second approach works when there are no duplicated indexes in the data frame:

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr)
df %>% rowwise() %>% summarise(index = index, value = list(lo:hi)) %>% unnest()

# Source: local data frame [10 x 2]

#    index value
#    <dbl> <int>
# 1      1     1
# 2      1     2
# 3      2     3
# 4      2     4
# 5      2     5
# 6      3     6
# 7      3     7
# 8      3     8
# 9      3     9
# 10     3    10


df %>% group_by(index) %>% summarise(value = list(lo:hi)) %>% unnest()

# Source: local data frame [10 x 2]

#    index value
#    <dbl> <int>
# 1      1     1
# 2      1     2
# 3      2     3
# 4      2     4
# 5      2     5
# 6      3     6
# 7      3     7
# 8      3     8
# 9      3     9
# 10     3    10
```

Comment: how did you print and copy and paste the output tables to that nice format?

Comment: Is this better than yours? I consider them no difference?

Comment: I printed df to console. Then I copy and pasted the output to the script. Then commented it out. Then indented... super manual. Do you have a quicker way?